# Objective-C Files Compile Slow on macOS Catalina

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compilation, xcode11, macos-catalina

After updating to Catalina, our Xcode project with both Swift and Objective-C files takes 4-5 times longer to compile than it did before the update. After digging into the build logs, we are seeing a huge increase on our Objective-C files. An example file went from ~0.4 seconds to 21.2 seconds. Swift seems to be consistent, it's just the Objective-C files that are now taking forever to compile.

Any idea what could cause such a change in compilation for Objective-C after upgrading to Catalina?

Using:

- Xcode 11.1
- macOS Catalina
- Swift 5.1

Comment: i have the same problem, I haven't resolved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something was updated in Catalina and doesn't seem to be an issue anymore. My machine (and others on the team) were force restarted one morning outside of our control and the issue was mysteriously gone.